# Python cursor.fetchall() returns empty tuple

Tags: python, sql

I'm learning python and hit a roadblock working on a web application.
I'm trying to fetch data from a local database (mariadb), and when I try to print out the results, all I see is `()`.

**This function gets data from the DB:**

```
def getHikeInfo(name):

    conn, cursor = getConnectionAndCursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM hiking WHERE name = %s", [name])

    # fetch the results
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    # clean up
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return data
```

**This code calls the function:**

```
if 'name' in form:
    #unpack into python variable
    name=form['name'].value
    print name #debug purpose to check name is proper
    data = getHikeInfo(name)
    print data #prints '()'

else:
    data = getAllHikes()
    showAllHikes(data)
```

I've tried a bunch of things from changing the way I concatenate the name to passing the name as a parameter and nothing seems to work.
The name is 100% definitely included in the table. I can't seem to see what the problem might be.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mariadb, but does it have a command line interface where you can run the SQL query just to make absolutely sure that it returns results? That way you can confirm that it a problem with the code.

You could also have the program print the statement that it is sending, so that you can verify it is being put together correctly from the variable.

Comment: @SamIreland I ran the query on mariadb interface and it outputs the expected result. The problem seems to be with the Python code. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @ishyfishy, does my post need any additional clarification in order to constitute the answer your question? Please let me know, so I can make edits. Thanks!

Comment: @Abdou, hi Abdou, I waited as I wanted to see if there were any other potential answers. I tried all your suggestions and none worked, unfortunately. I had to merge this function with another in my code to make it work. The error seemed to be in my main. I will accept your answer nonetheless.

Comment: @ishyfishy It's fine to leave it unchecked as long as it's working for you. I just wanted to see if there was anything else I could add to the answer to make it more fitting. If you could debug the code and determine where the error is occurring, people here could help you get to the core of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `name` argument for your `getHikeInfo` function is a string, rewrite your `cur.execute` call like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM hiking WHERE name = '%s'"% name)
```

But if you're passing in a list to your `getHikeInfo` function, then you may have to do:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM hiking WHERE name IN {}".format(tuple(name)))
```

So, you would need to rewrite your `getHikeInfo` function as follows:

```
def getHikeInfo(name):

    conn, cursor = getConnectionAndCursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM hiking WHERE name = %s"%name)
    #if you're passing in a list for `name` then you would need to use my second suggestion.

    # fetch the results
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    # clean up
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return data
```

As long as your table contains data fitting the condition defined by the `name` argument, you should be able to see some results with this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a sql injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: Not every SQL query you see is a target for an injection. OP asked for a solution and one was provided. It is their responsibility to sanitize the query.

Comment: It is entirely irresponsible to provide unsafe examples, especially when someone says that they are just learning.  This query takes external input, so it clearly *is* a target for injection.  Even if we somehow knew it wasn't, code tends to be reused so intentionally implementing it in an unsafe way is asking for trouble.